# How can I use the Angular Loading Bar explicitly for various wait conditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

The app I am working on does most of its navigation by Ajax loading HTML templates. The Angular Loading Bar works great for this, because it uses interceptors to monitor most `$http` requests. It does, however, have `start()`  and `complete()` methods, which work as I require, starting and stopping the load indicator independently of any `$http` requests.

My problem is I can't figure out how to get access this service, either directly, or by injecting it into a control, to access these two methods I want. The only evidence of anything to do with this service is only found in the first two lines of the Angular app:

```
var MlamAngularApp = angular.module('MlamAngularApp', ['kendo.directives', 'ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate']);

MlamAngularApp.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;
}]);
```

There follow a lot of declarations of services, factories, and controllers, in the form:

```
MlamAngularApp.service('QuoteService', QuoteService);
MlamAngularApp.factory('ApplicationCancelFactory', ApplicationCancelFactory);
MlamAngularApp.controller('MlamController', MlamController);
```

and I somehow suspect the Loading Bar should be included there somewhere, but really have no clue if it should or how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your speculation is correct. Injecting `cfpLoadingBar` to the controller would grant the access. A working example given below starts and ends loading manually, as well as sets the loading spinner and loading bar via its provider.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-loading-bar']);
app.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true; // Show the spinner.
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true; // Show the bar.
}]);
app.controller('appCtrl', ['cfpLoadingBar', function(cfpLoadingBar) {
    cfpLoadingBar.start(); // Start loading.
    setTimeout( function() {
        cfpLoadingBar.complete(); // End loading.
    }, 1000);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl"></div>
```